# ECS S3 Upload Hang

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

```
 const object = new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: s3Bucket,
      Key: key,
      Body: fileData,
      ACL: acl,
    });
    const { $metadata } = await this.s3.send(object)
```

I am writing an upload function for my project. The above code work perfectly on my local, local-run docker image. However, once I run my image on the ECS with same access key and secret, it just hang there with no error message. The service on ECS can access to RDS, the only problem is uploading the file to s3.
I do not set up any private subnet in my VPC, im sure my s3 is able to upload. Any Idea?

I tried no matter aws-sdk v2 and v3. Tried a totally public s3 bucket. Works on local and local-runs image. But not on ECS

Comment: Hello Felix. Try getting onto your container and manually uploading a file to that bucket using the s3 commandline tool. That would at least rule out your code and you'll probably get a more useful error code if it times out. Let me know what happens.

Comment: I tried to log anything I can, but it just hang there, no error code at all....

Comment: Are you saying you already tried manually uploading it to s3 using the s3 commandline tool while on the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have your ECS task running in public subnets of your VPC, but you probably don't have public IPs assigned to your tasks. You need to enable public IP assignments in your ECS task definition. If you don't want to do that, you could add an S3 Gateway VPC Endpoint to your VPC.